# Need help understanding some source code (shell scripting) for pianobar

Tags: shell

So im reading some source code for control-pianobar to get an idea on how to configure pianobar, but one part that confuses me is this part

```
fold="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/pianobar"
if [[ "$fold" == "/pianobar" ]]; then
    fold="$HOME/.config/pianobar"
    blankicon="$fold""$blankicon"
fi
```

Why would this be included? Isnt fold already speciffies at that dir, so why restate it? Any help would be appreicated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed.

That appears to be redundant fallback support for when `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is unset/empty.

Perhaps the `:-` expansion was added later than the original `if` version?

Comment: Makes sense that it would be for fallback support actually

Comment: The `:-` expansion is already fallback for `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` not being set. I don't see any way for that `if` to *ever* trigger.

Comment: Oops didnt see that part in your comment! Just reviewed the source code and it appears youre right! That was added later on!

Comment: Author here. Yes, the expansion was added later, and the if just stuck around. This sort of thing happens with code you wrote 5 years ago. 